# Looking for proper grep function pattern parameter syntax

Tags: r, regex

I am trying something like this:

```
animal_stories <- c("dogs are loyal", "cats are moody",
                    "cat was chasing mouse who was chased by dog",
                    "aabjjada adda", "dont play cat and mouse game", "ssss", 
                    "dog and cats are never friends", "jduh hisdsaug")  

grep("cat AND mouse|dog", animal_stories, ignore.case=T)
```

and expecting an output similar to:

```
## [1] cat was chasing mouse who was chased by dog
## [2] dog and cats are never friends
## [3] dont play cat and mouse game
```

Comment: unclear for me . Could you post a sample input along with expected output?

Comment: the inputs be the character vector:

 c("cat was chasing mouse who was chased by dog","aabjjada adda", "dont play cat and mouse game", "ssss", "dog and cats are never friends", "jduh  hisdsaug")

Comment: Please specify the rules. What was the problem with the deleted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex matches (a) `"cat"` followed by `"dog"` or `"mouse"` and (b) `"dog"` or `"mouse"` followed by `"cat"`.

```
grep("(dog|mouse).*cat|cat.*(dog|mouse)", animal_stories, ignore.case = TRUE, value = TRUE)
# [1] "cat was chasing mouse who was chased by dog"
# [2] "dont play cat and mouse game"               
# [3] "dog and cats are never friends"
```